How does the height of the hole on the bottle affect the burning time of the candles?
We took 3 identical bottles and drilled some holes on the side, each bottle had a hole but at different heights. Then we covered the burning candles with the 3 bottles and measured the burning time. However, we got a variety of results.
I tried to search some projects to see which bottle could make the flame last longer, and who had got a more accurate result. Some concluded that the bottle with a higher hole made it last longest, and that with a lower hole made it last shortest. (The flame was at the same height as the medium height hole.) While another project concluded that if the hole was closer to the flame, the flame lasted longer, which means the bottle with a hole at the middle should make the flame lasted longer if the flame was at the medium height.
Which conclusion was more reliable and what's the mechanic in the experiments?

Not sure about your description of the experiments: did you use candles small in diameter and put the bottles upside down on the candle? Did you allow or prevent airflow from the bottom?

Yes. We put a layer of water in a basin, then burned the candle standing in the basin, and covered it with the bottle.

For initial analysis first consider a bottle with no holes. When there is no hole the hot combustion products with depleted oxygen rise to the top of the bottle and form a gradually increasing layer there and eventually this depleted layer extends down to the flame and the lack of oxygen causes the flame to extinguish.
Another simple analytical thought experiment is to consider a bottle with two holes. The depleted hot air continually exits from the top hole and cold air entering the lower hole continually replenishes the oxygen so that the candle can continue to burn until it reached the base of the candle.
For a single small hole, things are a bit more complicated. The flow is a bit more turbulent and chaotic because hot air is trying to exit the hole while cold denser air is trying to enter the hole at the same time. Another complication is that the air inside the bottle is being heated by the candle, thereby increasing the pressure inside the bottle. This higher pressure in the bottle relative to the pressure outside, will tend to prevent cold replenishing air entering.
The pressure difference will tend fluctuate due to momentum considerations and it is possible for some replenishing air to enter periodically in a slightly chaotic manner, possible accounting for the variation in results you obtained.
Having said that, lets compare the situation for the candle between having a high hole versus a low hole. For the high hole, the hot layer at the top builds up until it reached the top hole and then starts exhausting depleted hot air and letting a certain amount of replenishing air in delaying the time it takes for the oxygen depleted layer to build up to the point where it reaches the flame and puts it out. In the bottle with the lower hole, some cold un-depleted air is forced out by the increased pressure in the bottle, but this does nothing to prevent or slow down the build up of the hot depleted layer reaching the flame and putting it out. There seems to be clear case that the candle in the bottle with high hole should burn for longer than the bottle with the low hole.
For the bottle that has a mid height hole, things are a bit more unpredictable. If the candle is near the side of the bottle with the hole and the hole is large, then there is a continuous circulation of fresh replenishing air to the flame and once the candle has burned down sufficiently, the situation is now a bit like the bottle with the top hole because the middle hole is now higher than the flame.
An additional factor to be considered is that for the mid height hole, the air entering and exiting the side hole cause a certain amount of turbulence in the interface between the hot depleted air the cold air, mixing oxygen rich cold air into the depleted hot layer and since this interface is near the level of the flame an certain amount of additional oxygen is fed to the flame keeping it alive long enough to burn down to a lower level where there are stores of richer cold air to use. The location of the middle hole relative to the flame height is probably critical. Did the different groups use the same definition for the height of the flame? Did they use the base of the flame or the middle of the flame as the reference point?

Thanks for your explanation. I'm sorry for the ambiguity. A group used exactly the same bottles. The bottles used by each group were a bit different in shape, but their heights and volume were similar. I'm pretty sure the size of the holes were the same and they're all small since we heated the same metal chopsticks to drill the holes. However, the middle hole was not clearly defined. I think the candles were sometimes higher than it and sometimes lower in each group. That should be one factor in the variation. And there's a layer of water to prevent airflow from the bottom.

Thanks for the clarification. I have edited my answer taking into account the additional information and generally cleaned up and shortened the answer.

@qsfhubv if the holes were small, it may also make a difference if the drilling is smooth or rough. As KDP explained, the exhaust air rises. This implies, that the outside temperature as well as heat transfer through the glass of the bottle may play tricks on your experiment. I'm not an expert on airflow, but if the inside air expands by heating and also by chemical reactions, it might be that the holes only let gas out but no air in.

@GyroGearloose I agree with you that the size and shape of the holes is a critical feature that may or may not allow a two way flow of hot and cold air and how turbulent the flow is.
